# Updating classes on a react component

Tags: css, reactjs, mobx-react

I have a functional component and my data in the storage changes, in connection with this the component is redrawn, but the classes remain from the old one

```
{menu.map((option: any, index: any) => (
     <Text
         key={index}
         className={cn('menu-title', {
             'menu-active': index === 0 ?? true,
         })}
         onClick={(e) => changeActive(option, e)}
         >
         {option}
     </Text>
))}
```

through the 'menu-active', I set the active first element after redrawing, but this only works on initial page load

when the data in the mobx-store changes, the menu element is redrawn, but the class remains assigned to the old element, and the menu-active-condition does not work

Comment: the menu is declared in the current component and an object with data from the mobx-store is assigned to it

I am sure that it is being redrawn, because the values themselves are updated (after iterating through the menu.map the values already different)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confusing as you're always assigning the "menu-active" className to the first menu item by doing `'menu-active': index === 0`. Also the `??` should be used when [the left-side of the operand is either null or undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) so in this case that operator is not necessary at all. And as a final note, I'd assume you should be comparing the current menu item index to a variable that contains the active item index instead of always to zero?

Comment: I assign the active menu class to the first item, because I want the first item to become active after updating the menu

Comment: Might be a key issue then, as you're using the index as key which technically speaking does not change between renders. Don't you have a unique identifier for each menu item? Even the menu item text might be a better identifier as the index since the you appear to be changing the array altogether.

Comment: about uniqueness, I think you are right, initially it was easiest for me to assign through an index, because it is logical that there is a zero element in any array

but without knowing the contents of the array, I don't know how else I can select the first element

Comment: You can select the first element by comparing like you're doing. I'd just switch to a simple `index === 0` without the nullish coalescing operator. However the key prop should receive something that's uniquely identifies each item in that context. Meaning that when you change the array items, React should be able to see that the elements changed since the elements have different keys. For instance, if the menu items text is unique, you could use those. If that same information comes from a CMS you might have access to a database uid / auto-increment of sorts.